# Outlook web add-in starts with error when use displayInFrame:true

Tags: javascript, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I created a custom office add-in and it loads properly with Word/excel online, but shows loading errors through Outlook Online (tested with Chrome, IE and Edge) even though clicking through the prompt buttons eventually loads the add-in and everything works as expected.

I open a link with a different domain in popup using an iframe.

```
window.OFS.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(paramUrl, { height: 80, width: 80, displayInIframe: true }, dialogCallback);
```

New pop up window is created. But html code contains wrong block with add-in error.

1. Receive Add-in Error message - Something went wrong and we couldn't start this add-in. Please try again later or contact your system administrator.
   [image]
2. Click the Retry button
3. Page is displayed again in the taskpane with the overlay and loading animation
4. Receive Add-in Error message - This add-in may not load properly, but you can still try to start it.
   [image]
5. Click the Start button
6. The page loads and everything works as expected

This issue is outlook online specific and appears only when we use displayInIframe: true. We use it (open pop up in iframe) as pop ups are getting blocked by the browser.

Any advice on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Does the page your opening contain a reference to `office.js` and an `office.initialize` method?

Comment: let me check, but I'm opening the same external content from Word/Excel with the same code as from Outlook and it works... Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(startAddress, {displayInFrame:true}, callback);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Marc's comment, adding a reference to `office.js` and an `office.initialize` method to the content opened in iframe solved the issue.